# creating a directory exclusion list for find

Tags: bash, find

Im trying to exclude a list of directories to be excluded from Find. This list needs to be regularly updated hence the need to put the names in the file.

So I have tried this so far

```
find  $HOME  $(printf " -not  \( -path  $HOME/%s -prune \) " $(cat $HOME/exclude)) -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\\*]*" | while read -r file;do echo $file; done
```

This results in an

```
"find: \(: unknown primary or operator"
```

I have tried the echoing the output and its formatted correctly, is it possible to do this with Find?

Comment: what about filtering output of `find` with a "negative" grep, i.e. `find ... | grep -vFf excludeList.txt` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that would work nicely for a small amount of files, sadly it still parses all, what Im trying to do is exclude parsing certain folders that have thousands of files

Comment: so how many dirs do you want to list in the file(?) `$HOME/exclude` ? Good luck.

Comment: 7 dirs at the moment although this could change

Comment: I've never mastered `-prune`. but do you think making `-not -path d1 -prune d2 -prune d3 ...` (where you can have a dynamic list of `d`) is your goal? I think I just recently learned something that will help with solution. (But I'm leaving now for a while, and will have limited time today). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with some assistance got there in the end. So This is one way of doing it

```
SUPPORT_PATH="$HOME/Library/Application Support/App"
EXCLUDE_FILE="exclude"
defexcludefolder=".Cache"
def_opts=( -not "(" -path "$HOME/$defexcludefolder" -prune ")" )

#add defaults to exclusion list
exclusion_list=("${def_opts[@]}")

while IFS= read -r line; do

user_opts=( -not "(" -path "$HOME/$line" -prune ")" )
exclusion_list+=("${user_opts[@]}")
user_opts=()


done < <(grep "" "$SUPPORT_PATH/$EXCLUDE_FILE")

find  $HOME  "${exclusion_list[@]}"  -name "*[<>:/|?#%\\\\*]*"
```